# Is Linux safe from NetBIOS viruses

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virus, netbios

I don't understand anything about computer viruses, but I have a very simple question:

If a virus targets NetBIOS, is a computer running Ubuntu safe?

Answer (score 0):

Latest Linux distributions don't use NetBIOS by default,
unless you have installed SAMBA.

And for viruses, there is no reason to fear NetBIOS viruses more than the other
kinds.

For more information see :
[Why can Windows machines resolve local names when Linux can't?](https://serverfault.com/questions/352305/why-can-windows-machines-resolve-local-names-when-linux-cant).

Answer (score 0):

Chances are not really - but its worth remembering, the viruses don't directly attack the protocol, but rather flaws in a specific implantation of a protocol. If samba's flavour of netbios had a bug, and it was not fixed in the system you had (and this can happen in many embedded devices), it could be potentially exploited. It is *less* likely on a patched system, and there's many people looking at samba and there's ongoing patches.

So, Never? No. However its unlikely that unless the virus attacks a specific vulnerability in the build of linux you have, you'd get affected.

At the end of the day common sense - patching regularly, and running limited accounts with good, sensibly strong passwords, and not plugging in random junk, and opening ports you don't need to the outside world is our best friend here.